# how to get image url from style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have `html` `DOM` like this i want to grab image `url`.

```
 <img src="constant/spacer.gif" style="background-image:url(https://example1.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">

    <img src="constant/spacer.gif" style="background-image:url(https://example2.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
```

**my expected output:** `["https://example1.com/image/image1.png","https://example1.com/image/image1.png"];`

right now i'm using this code

```js
arr = [];

$('.images-thumb').each(function(){

   arr.push($(this).attr('style')); // furthur i don't know 
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" style="background-image:url(https://example1.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
<img src="" style="background-image:url(https://example2.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
```

Furthur i don't know how to exactly grab

```
["https://example1.com/image/image1.png","https://example1.com/image/image1.png"];
```

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: You can give source of image in src attribute why use it as background?

Comment: i'm doing it for client,so i cannot change the structure of `DOM`

Comment: @DilipG I have posted an answer and I have tested it and it works. just give it a try

Comment: @DilipG could you accept the most appropriate answer and mark it closed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

`url = url.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');`
This will remove `url('` and `url("` from the beginning of the string if it is present and `")` resp. `')` from the end.

```
arr = [];

$('.images-thumb').each(function(){

   var $style = $(this).attr('style');
   var $url = $style.replace(/^background-image:url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '').replace(/\)/, '');
   arr.push($url); // further know you know :-P
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: it is working but i'm getting this `)` can you remove and update

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images-thumb');
  var image, arr=[];
  for(var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
    image = window.getComputedStyle(images[i]).backgroundImage;
    arr.push(image.substr(5, image.length-7));
  }
console.log(arr);
```

Pure JS method to grab all the styles of the element.

Comment: Still not what OP require. Your code only returns `"url("https://example1.com/image/image1.png")"`

Comment: @shivgre Updated now. It just needed to extract the substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can give the image path in src attribute, otherwise the script will be like below

  arr = [];

$('.images-thumb').each(function(){
  var txt = $(this).attr('style');
  first = txt.indexOf('(');
    second = txt.indexOf(')');
    arr.push(txt.substr(first+1,second-first-1));
});
console.log(arr);
Just check once
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the unwanted text with empty string "" :

Example snippet:

```js
arr = [];

$('.images-thumb').each(function() {

  arr.push($(this).css("background-image").replace("url(\"", "").replace("\")", ""));
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" style="background-image:url(https://example1.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
<img src="" style="background-image:url(https://example2.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery `css("background-image")` selector  and regular expression to get the desired result.

```js
arr = [];

$('.images-thumb').each(function(){

   arr.push($(this).css("background-image").replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, ''));
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" style="background-image:url(https://example1.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
<img src="" style="background-image:url(https://example2.com/image/image1.png);" class="images-thumb">
```